# How to create splash page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to display splash page at the beginning of a site. How can I do this in WordPress?

I have created the static home page by going to `admin->setting->reading` .. But I need to display one page before that, it will ask the  user to click the enter button for entering into the site.

Please someone help me!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need a splash-screen for? Setting a static page to load first under Settings->Reading is the best way to accomplish this. Why not set the static page to your splash screen, and then link to your static home page from said page?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could create a page-template for that specific page, and then select that template in the page settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for this..
Here is mine:

On the **root** of your **wordpress** installation, in the **index.php,
 before** the comment
**Loads the WordPress Environment and Template**, add something like this

```
if( (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'yourdomain.com') === false) && !$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']){
    include 'splash.html';
    exit();
}
```

Then edit/create your splash.html.

Please note that any **wordpress update might overwrite** the **index.php** on the **root**.

Hope it helps anyone!